# Saving a symbolic equation for later use?

Tags: matlab

From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/toolbox/symbolic/brvfu8o-1.html#brvfxem-1), I'm trying to solve a symbolic system of equations like this

```
syms x y z;
[x, y, z] = solve('z = 4*x', 'x = y', 'z = x^2 + y^2')
x =
0
2

y =
0
2

z =
0
8
```

except that my equations are generated at different points in the m-file and with random coefficients. My question is how can I accomplish the following...

```
// Generate the first equation.
n = *random number generated here*;
E1 = (z == n*x + 2*n);   // <--- How to save this symbolic equation to use in "solve(...)" later?

// Other work, generate other eqs.
...

// Solve system of eqs.
[x, y, z] = solve( E1 , E2, E3)   // What/How to call/use the previously saved symbolic equations.
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

Updated to better explain objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) if you want to keep the randomly generated value of `n` for later use with `solve`:

```
n = *random number generated here*;
E1 = (z == n*x + 2*n);
Eq1 = sprintf('z == %f*x + 2*%f',n,n);
```

You can play with the parameters on `%f` to see how much precision you want to include.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm using 2011a if that makes any difference. I'm creating a few symbolic equations at different points in the script and I want to save them so, in the end, I can solve for the 'syms' values. I updated my original post to better reflect this. Any additional help on how this can be accomplished would be appreciated!

Comment: How can I convert the symbolic equation to a string immediately after it is created so I don't have to keep "x" in the workspace the whole time (or if I want to reuse it to generate another number for another equation)?

Comment: It is saved as a string so you can clear `x` if you want ; the variable name `x` is stored, not the value.

Comment: Exactly. So say I write `Eq1 = 'A^2 + B + 2C -x == D';`, the string will include `x` not the random number (e.g. 3.839). Then, if I clear `x` and eventually get to `solve(E1, E2,...)` it won't be able to find the value `x`, correct? Or am I missing something...

Comment: No, you're right. So you want `Eq1 = 'A^2 + B + 2C - 3.839 == D`?

Comment: Yes, but that `x` value will be a randomly generated number each time the m-file runs. So I'm wondering what the syntax is to 1.) create the symbolic equation using `x` and then 2.) save the equation {object/string/whatever} to use in `solve(...)` later.

Comment: My question is in the later call to `solve`, do you need `x` (whatever it is at the time) or the random value?

Comment: The duplicate question I opened after you answered this one explains it better (I replaced my original post). I just need the random number `x` to generate the random `E1` equation, then I only care about preserving the generated `E1` equation (in whatever format) until I get to `solve()`.

Comment: So you want to preserve the value of the random number for future use?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16063/discussion-between-john-and-jacob)