# Symbolic Equation Solver, Saving Symbolic Equations

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saving a symbolic equation for later use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203456/saving-a-symbolic-equation-for-later-use)

From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/toolbox/symbolic/brvfu8o-1.html#brvfxem-1), I'm trying to solve a symbolic system of equations like this

```
syms x y z;
[x, y, z] = solve('z = 4*x', 'x = y', 'z = x^2 + y^2')
x =
0
2

y =
0
2

z =
0
8
```

except that my equations are generated at different points in the m-file and with random coefficients. My question is how can I accomplish the following...

```
// Generate the first equation.
n = *random number generated here*;
E1 = (z == n*x + 2*n);   // <--- How to save this symbolic equation to use in "solve(...)" later?

// Other work, generate other eqs.
...

// Solve system of eqs.
[x, y, z] = solve( E1 , E2, E3)   // What/How to call/use the previously saved symbolic equations.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't post the same question only a few hours apart.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if I should just completely redo my original question post since @Jacob already answered, so I made a new one.